# Differential equation: $f'(x)+af^{2}(x)+bf(x)+c=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following differential equation:

$$f'(x)+af^{2}(x)+bf(x)+c=0,$$

where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: I edited my question. First version was trivial.

Comment: This is also a separable ODE that you can solve with standard integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edited ODE is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). For $y=f(x)$:
$$
y'=-c-by-ay^2
$$
Then $v=-ay$ satisfies: $$v'=v^2+bv+ac.$$

Let $v=\frac{-u'}{u}$. Then $u$ satisfies:
$$
u''+bu'+acu=0
$$
which can easily be solved (I can edit my answer to add the solution if required). A solution to the original equation will then be: $$f(x)=y=\frac{u'}{au}.$$

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @Leon I edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

$$f'(x)=-(ax^2+bx+c)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=-(ax^2+bx+c)$$
Integrate both sides with respect to x:
$$f(x)=-\frac{a}{3}x^3-\frac{b}{2}x^2-cx+k$$
Where k is a constant.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @Leon Then it's Ricatti's equation: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor/Riccati

Comment: Thank you very much! I do not know why they put on hold my question...

Comment: As I see @Test123 gave you a more detailed solution. I suppose they put on hold because it was trivial, and you did not show any effort in solving that. And I do thank you too, I've found out that the differential equation I want to solve is also a special case of the Chini's equation while I was looking for yours' solution.